# Global shortcut for New Mail in Thunderbird

Tags: keyboard, email

I would like to have a global shortcut key to send a new message using Thunderbird in Mac OS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [assign a keyboard shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Thunderbird"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Thunderbird"
    repeat 10 times
        try
            click menu item "Message" of menu 1 of menu item "New" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            return
        on error
            delay 0.1
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

If Thunderbird was not open before the script was run, there is a short delay before the menu bar is populated.

Edit: this does not reopen the main window <s>or switch desktops if the main window is already open on a different desktop</s>:

```
launch application "Thunderbird"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Thunderbird"
    repeat 10 times
        try
            click menu item "Message" of menu 1 of menu item "New" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            exit repeat
        on error
            delay 0.1
        end try
    end repeat
    set frontmost to true
end tell
```

Edit 2: The second script also *sometimes* switches desktops, but I couldn't figure out how to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks, this mostly works, but still has the problem that the workspace changes and that the main Thunderbird window reopens. I just would like to have a new message window in the current workspace.

Comment: @anumi I edited the answer to add a second script.

Comment: The second solution does not reopen the main window, but still switches workspaces. But that's an improvement!

Comment: How do i do the same thing for Windows?