# Global shortcut for menu item within menubar bar application

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, menu-bar

I'd like to create a applescript that selects the "History" menu item from the menubar application [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html).

I'm aware of how to create a [global shortcut for an application with multiple menus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102419/global-shortcut-for-new-mail-in-thunderbird), but I'm unclear of how to do this for an app that runs exclusively in the menu bar and doesn't have a "File" menu.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: screenshot of Jing application]

Comment: I do not use Jing, so can you run the following AppleScript _code_ in Script Editor and let me know what the result was? `tell application "System Events" to get description of every menu bar item of menu bars of process "SystemUIServer"` I'm looking to see if Jing has a _description_, i.e. "jing" or something like that is in the results returned.

Comment: The result is empty `{}`

Comment: Replacing  "SystemUIServer" with "Jing" I get:
`{{"menu bar item", "menu bar item"}, {"menu extra", "menu extra"}}`

Comment: What OS version are you using?

Comment: El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Running
 `tell application "System Events"
 tell process "Jing"
  name of every menu of menu bar 1
 end tell
end tell`
 I get
 `{"Apple", "Jing"}`

Comment: Interesting, I'm using 10.11.5 and the code I asked you to run runs fine for me however your code, when replacing `tell process "Jing"` with an app I'm running it will not compile because of `name` afterwards. This may be due in fact to some difference between 10.11.5 and 10.11.6 and as such since I do not have the latter and our code does work as expected I'm going to have to bow out, sorry. Good luck! (I just do not want to install Jing.)